# How to Fix arrow and logo slider in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have  a website, Which contains slider

I have used this code to for it, the problem is that when I click arrow/whenever it slides, the slider passes under arrow. It's not what I want, I want the slide to pass it before arrow not under it.

```css
.enligne-fa,
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #f3ab2a !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">

<!-- Gallery starts here -->

<section class="clients-slider mb-5">
  <div class="container-fluid company-bg-gallery">
    <div class="row  mb-4">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <h2 class="slider-text text-white pt-5">Gallery</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row my-5">
      <div class="col-lg-12 my-5">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active mx-lg-5">
              <div class="container mx-lg-5">
                <div class="row mx-lg-5">
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item mx-lg-5">
              <div class="container mx-lg-5">
                <div class="row mx-lg-5">
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item mx-lg-5">
              <div class="container mx-lg-5">
                <div class="row mx-lg-5">
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                  <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img class="d-block img-fluid px-2" src="https://dummyimage.com/100%20x%20100/000000/fff.png" alt="First slide"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev text-primary" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="fas fa-caret-left enligne-fa" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next text-primary" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="fas fa-caret-right enligne-fa" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Gallery ends here -->
```

And Currently all three photo passes at a time. I need something like [codepen](https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE) but with arrow as mine and in BS4. Also all slide should pass before arrow and should look good on mobile as well.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's how it was designed to work - It works exactly the same in Bootstraps examples on their website. The carousel is being rendered with the "arrows" inside, not outside, of the carousel (you can use developer tools to view this).  Why not just use the codepen example you posted if it's closer to what you're wanting?

Answer (score 0):

Your slider is in a container-fluid, which takes the complete width of the screen. Therefore your slider will take up the whole width in the animation. I would try to put your slider in a container in a fluid container. Your controls should be in the fluid container, and your slider in the container. A container will set the with to the grid itself.

something like

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   [ARROWS HERE]
   <div class="container">[SLIDER HERE]</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Sorry to say it didn't work, i have code embeded, can you please try there other requirements as well, Please refer question

Comment: Do you know a bit of javascript? To quickly resolve both your problems I suggest using Slick for your slider or carousel. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Quickstart
* include jQuery
* include Slick
* Add the Slick config at the bottom of your page
`$('.multiple-items').slick({
     infinite: true,
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 1 
   }); `